# Convert a date format

Tags: command-line, date

I have one problem with my date format. I want to change from one format to the other and vice verse. My date formats are:

- Format1 :  1/24/2014
- Format2 :  Jan 24

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Using GNU `date`. From format 1 to 2:

```
LC_ALL=C date --date=1/24/2014 +"%b %-d"              
Jan 24
```

And from 2 to 1:

```
date --date="Jan 24" +"%-m/%-d/%Y"
1/24/2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ksh93`:

```
$ printf "%(%-m/%-d/%Y)T\n" "Jan 24"
1/24/2014
$ LC_ALL=C printf "%(%b %-d)T\n" 1/24/2014
Jan 24
```

Portably

```
d=1/24/2014
echo "$d:Jan1:Feb2:Mar3:Apr4:May5:Jun6:Jul7:Aug8:Sep9:Oct10:Nov11:Dec12:" |
  sed -n 's|^0*\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)/0*\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)/.*:.*\(...\)\1:.*|\3 \2|p'

d='Jan 24'
echo "$d:Jan1Feb2Mar3Apr4May5Jun6Jul7Aug8Sep9Oct10Nov11Dec12" |
  sed -n "s|^\(...\) 0*\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*\1\([0-9]*\).*|\3/\2/$(date +%Y)|p"
```

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD and OS X `date`:

```
$ LC_ALL=C date -jf '%b %d' 'Jan 24' +%-d/%-m/%Y
24/1/2014
$ LC_ALL=C date -jf %d/%m/%Y 24/1/2014 '+%b %-d'
Jan 24
```